# Create a new dictionary from an old one, grouping key years by decade and finding the average of the ranges

Tags: python, dictionary, average

I want to create a new dictionary from an old one. I want to group the keys in decades and find the average of the values for each new key.

```
d={1850:1,1851:2,1853:3,1854:2,1860:5,1861:6,1862:0,1865:1}
av=0
i=0
new_dict={}
a=1850
total=0
for key, value in d.items():
        if key in range(a,a+10):
            total=total+value
            i=i+1
        av=total/i
        new_key=(a,a+10)
        new_dict[new_key]=av
        a=a+10
        if a>1870:
            break

print(new_dict)
```

I want my results to be in the form:

```
new_dict={(1850,1860):2,(1860,1865):3}
```

I want the last group/key to reach the last year and close the group.

But firstly I struggle with assigning the average of the values. My results are:

```
{(1850, 1860): 1.0, (1860, 1870): 1.0, (1870, 1880): 1.0}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group the counts by decade while keeping track of the largest year value along the way. Then, compute the average of each decade, using the last year as necessary.

Note that there is no corresponding first year adjustment, which wasn't in your specification, but can be added easily if desired following the same strategy as last year (find the global min year, then use the max of the global min and the current year as the first item in each tuple range).

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {1850: 1, 1851: 2, 1853: 3, 1854: 2, 1860: 5, 1861: 6, 1862: 0, 1865: 1}
group_size = 10
by_decade = defaultdict(list)
last_year = 0

for year, count in d.items():
    by_decade[year//group_size*group_size].append(count)
    last_year = max(last_year, year)

avg_by_decade = {
    (year, min(last_year, year + group_size)): sum(counts) / len(counts) 
    for year, counts in by_decade.items()
}

print(avg_by_decade) # => {(1850, 1860): 2.0, (1860, 1865): 3.0}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,it is actually working despite the fact that i don't know how defaultdict works.Super elegant solution.

Comment: If I wanted to solve it without using the collections module ? Does my code makes at least any  sense (partially solved)??? @ggorlen

Comment: The existing code doesn't make much sense to me. Why not use `collections`? You can avoid `defaultdict` by adding `if key not in by_decade: by_decade[key] = []` but I don't see any advantage to this because `defaultdict` was invented exactly to solve that problem.